# Connect Keeps Failing With Error 10049 in C

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, sockets, winsock

I'm new to socket programming and this is my first server-client program. The program was working perfectly fine at first, but when I copied my code from Server.c and Client.c to a new project in Visual Studio, my client is now refusing to connect and throws the error 10049. I can still connect to my server if I use telnet from command prompt.

I am surprised as to why my client would stop working when I copy the code to another empty project, nothing else has changed.

I have tried changing IP addresses, port numbers and port forwarding using my public address to no avail. I have confirmed my computer's IP using ipconfig and it is correctly inputted in my code, as well as the port number. The program compiles fine with no errors whatsoever.

Server.c

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>


#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

void start_server(const char* ip_address, int port_number);
int server_sock, client_sock;

void main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    start_server("192.168.0.24", 100);
    system("pause");    
}

void start_server(const char* ip_address, int port_number)
{
    WSADATA wsaData;

    int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != NO_ERROR) {
        wprintf(L"WSAStartup() failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    memset(&server_addr, 0, sizeof(server_addr));

    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(port_number);
    InetPton(AF_INET, "", &server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr);

    server_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (server_sock == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf(L"Socket creation failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Socket created!\n");
    }

    int bind_status = bind(server_sock, (struct sockaddr*) & server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));
    if (bind_status == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        wprintf(L"bind failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Bind was successful!\n");
    }

    int listen_status = listen(server_sock, 3);
    if (listen_status == -1) 
    {
        wprintf(L"listen failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Listening...\n");
    }

    client_sock = accept(server_sock, NULL, NULL);
    if (client_sock == -1)
    {
        wprintf(L"client socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Accepted new client!\n");
    }
}
```

Client.c

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>

#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")


void connect_server(const char* ip_address, int port_number);

int sock;

void main()
{
    connect_server("192.168.0.24", 100);
    send(sock, "test", 5, 0);
    system("pause");
}

void connect_server(const char* ip_address, int port_number)
{
    WSADATA wsaData;

    int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != NO_ERROR) {
        wprintf("WSAStartup() failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        exit(1);
    }

    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    memset(&server_addr, 0, sizeof(server_addr));

    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(port_number);
    InetPton(AF_INET, ip_address, &server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr);

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Socket creation failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Socket created!\n");
    }

    int connection_status = connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));
    if (connection_status == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("Connection failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Connected.\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: in the server code,  This statement: `void main(int argc, char* argv[])` will cause the compiler to output two warning messages about unused parameters.  Suggest using: `int main( void )`

Comment: in the server, regarding: `printf(L"Socket creation failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());`  and `wprintf(L"bind failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());`  1) error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`,  Suggest using `fprintf( stderr, .... )`  2) when an error occurs, that would be time to exit the program, perhaps by: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: OT: the server code fails to do anything after establishing the connection with the client

Comment: OT: sockets have type `sock_t`, which might be the same as `int` but the code should not assume that relationship

Comment: regarding: `wprintf("WSAStartup() failed with error: %d\n", iResult);`  the function: `wprintf()` expects the text to be 'wide', not ascii.  So the statement should be: `wprintf(L"WSAStartup() failed with error: %d\n", iResult);`

Comment: the same logic and syntax problems mentioned for the `server` code also exist for the client code.

Comment: @user3629249 Yeah I have my warnings turned off because this is part of a bigger project to cause a buffer overflow on the server side. That said, my client used to be able to connect to my server, now its constantly throwing 10049? I don't know if the warnings are the problem though.

Comment: before the client calls `send()` it should check the returned value from 'connect_server()` to assure that a socket was successfully created and connected, which means the function: `connect_server()` needs to return an indication of success/failure

Comment: you might try using `perror()` (or similar statement in windows) to have the system tell you what the error means

Comment: I tried using perror, returns "No error". The only error I get is from WSA, 10049

Comment: You stated that you turned off the dynamic IP address assigning.  That means that your computer now uses a static address.   This is NOT a good idea.  Better to use an appropriate function to retrieve the current IP address

Answer (score 1):

Try using your code with loopback address 127.0.0.1. If it works then definitely problem is with the combination of IP and Port number. Maybe use ipconfig /reset to reset your ip address.

Comment: This solved the problem. I think I've seen this before with a C# program on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

A very fast/simple search for `WSA error 10049` results in:

Winsock error 10049 typically occurs when you attempt to create a socket with an address not on this machine. For example if you have MDaemon running on a machine with an IP address of 192.168.0.1 and you attempt to bind MDaemon to 192.168.0.100 you will receive this error message.

So, you need to correct the IP address for the new computer.

Comment: I mentioned this in my question, the IP address is correct for my PC. It hasn't changed because I turned off automatic IP address assignment.